# Send and receive emails using apple mail / outlook when custom domain is connected to AppFog

Tags: email, outlook, appfog

The question pretty much says it all. It's possible to connect a custom domain to appfog, but how do I configure my mail programme to send and receive emails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect a custom domain to AppFog. You will need a paid plan to add one though. Its very easy to do through the Domain Names section of the console or through the command line interface. It then gives you the settings you'll need to configure your DNS records.

Regarding the email part of the question, this isn't managed through AppFog. You'll need to configure the MX records of the domain to a mail server/service. Often your registrar may provide a simple mail interface and either SMTP or POP3 access or you could hook it to something like Google Apps.

Comment: This is what I assumed. Thanks for confirming!